# Importing and removing duplicates from a massive amount of text files using C# and Redis

Tags: c#, ruby, multithreading, mongodb, performance

This is a bit of a doozy and it's been a while since I worked with C#, so bear with me:

I'm running a jruby script to iterate through 900 files (5 Mb - 1500 Mb in size) to figure out how many dupes STILL exist within these (already uniq'd) files. I had little luck with `awk`.

My latest idea was to insert them into a local MongoDB instance like so:

`db.collection('hashes').update({ :_id => hash}, { $inc: { count: 1} }, { upsert: true)`

... so that later I could just query it like `db.collection.where({ count: { $gt: 1 }  })` to get all the dupes.

This is working great except it's been over **24 hours** and at the time of writing I'm at 72,532,927 Mongo entries and growing.

I think Ruby's `.each_line` is bottlnecking the IO hardcore:

[image]

So what I'm thinking now is compiling a C# program which fires up a thread PER EACH FILE and inserts the line (md5 hash) into a Redis list.

From there, I could have another compiled C# program simply pop the values off and ignore the save if the count is `1`.

So the questions are:

> 1. Will using a compiled file reader and multithreading the file reads significantly improve performance?
> 2. Is using Redis even necessary? With a tremendous amount of AWS memory, could I not just use the threads to fill some sort of a list atomically and proceed from there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking... load them into a HashSet<class>. Hashset will handle duplicates for you. I just loaded over 23,000 files (3.7GB total) in like 6 minutes that way.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger HashSet filters dupes? Does it count them or does it just not accept them?

Comment: No dupes. It doesn't throw an error - it just ignores the second and all future dupes by not adding them.

Comment: AFAIK though, you have to add one at a time. If you try to do something like HashSet<string> myHashSet = new HashSet<string>(myList.Select(m=>m.FirstName).ToArray()); and there are dupe first names, you will get an error. Foreach(string name in) will be error-free.

Comment: If the bottleneck is really disk io, multithread it will not improve performance. It would very likely decrease it. From your description(Ruby's .each_line is slow), it is not clear whether disk io is the bottleneck. Redis is not necessary for your case. If you only want to find duplicates HashSet is enough. If you want to count the duplicates, use a Dictionary<class, int>

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I see no reason why HashSet should give error on non-unique input, it is one of typical use cases. Btw it accepts IEnumerable, there is no need to convert input to array.

Comment: Yeah, right - sorry. No ToArray() needed. Seems I remember throwing an error adding a range at a time with dupes, but I might not have remembered correctly. It's been a while. I AM, though, certain that HashSet is a fast way of filtering dupes from large lists (with the added benefit of fast lookup later).

Comment: There is possibility of collisions when computing hashes. Two distinct strings may end up having same hash.

Comment: You *may* run into memory issues with `HashSet<string>` and that amount of data, but it's worth a try as it's just a few lines of code (be sure to execute it in 64 bit though). For each line, if `hashSet.Add(line)` returns `true`, it means the line was added to the set, and therefore is not a duplicate. If the program blows up because of memory usage, a more elaborate solution will be required.

Comment: Did you try this and find out if it all fits into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
[New solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iUivNg). [Old solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9jTzy). The main idea is to calculate dummy hashes(just sum of all chars in string) of each line and store it in `Dictionary<ulong, List<LinePosition>> _hash2LinePositions`. It's possible to have multiple hashes in the same stream and it solves by List in Dictionary Value. When the hashes are the same, we read and compare the strings from the streams. LinePosition is using for storing info about line - position in stream and its length. I don't have such huge files as you, but my tests shows that it works. Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
public class Solution
{
    struct LinePosition
    {
        public long Start;
        public long Length;

        public LinePosition(long start, long count)
        {
            Start = start;
            Length = count;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Start: {0}, Length: {1}", Start, Length);
        }
    }
    class TextFileHasher : IDisposable
    {
        readonly Dictionary<ulong, List<LinePosition>> _hash2LinePositions;
        readonly Stream _stream;
        bool _isDisposed;

        public HashSet<ulong> Hashes { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public TextFileHasher(string name, Stream stream)
        {
            Name = name;
            _stream = stream;
            _hash2LinePositions = new Dictionary<ulong, List<LinePosition>>();
            Hashes = new HashSet<ulong>();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
        public void CalculateFileHash()
        {
            int readByte = -1;
            ulong dummyLineHash = 0;
            // Line start position in file
            long startPosition = 0;
            while ((readByte = _stream.ReadByte()) != -1) {
                // Read until new line
                if (readByte == '\r' || readByte == '\n') {
                    // If there was data
                    if (dummyLineHash != 0) {
                        // Add line hash and line position to the dict
                        AddToDictAndHash(dummyLineHash, startPosition, _stream.Position - 1 - startPosition);
                        // Reset line hash
                        dummyLineHash = 0;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Was it new line ?
                    if (dummyLineHash == 0)
                        startPosition = _stream.Position - 1;
                    // Calculate dummy hash
                    dummyLineHash += (uint)readByte;
                }
            }
            if (dummyLineHash != 0) {
                // Add line hash and line position to the dict
                AddToDictAndHash(dummyLineHash, startPosition, _stream.Position - startPosition);
                // Reset line hash
                dummyLineHash = 0;
            }
        }
        public List<LinePosition> GetLinePositions(ulong hash)
        {
            return _hash2LinePositions[hash];
        }
        public List<string> GetDuplicates()
        {
            List<string> duplicates = new List<string>();

            foreach (var key in _hash2LinePositions.Keys) {
                List<LinePosition> linesPos = _hash2LinePositions[key];
                if (linesPos.Count > 1) {
                    duplicates.AddRange(FindExactDuplicates(linesPos));
                }
            }
            return duplicates;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_isDisposed)
                return;

            _stream.Dispose();
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
        private void AddToDictAndHash(ulong hash, long start, long count)
        {
            List<LinePosition> linesPosition;
            if (!_hash2LinePositions.TryGetValue(hash, out linesPosition)) {
                linesPosition = new List<LinePosition>() { new LinePosition(start, count) };
                _hash2LinePositions.Add(hash, linesPosition);
            }
            else {
                linesPosition.Add(new LinePosition(start, count));
            }
            Hashes.Add(hash);
        }
        public byte[] GetLineAsByteArray(LinePosition prevPos)
        {
            long len = prevPos.Length;
            byte[] lineBytes = new byte[len];
            _stream.Seek(prevPos.Start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            _stream.Read(lineBytes, 0, (int)len);
            return lineBytes;
        }
        private List<string> FindExactDuplicates(List<LinePosition> linesPos)
        {
            List<string> duplicates = new List<string>();
            linesPos.Sort((x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));

            LinePosition prevPos = linesPos[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < linesPos.Count; i++) {
                if (prevPos.Length == linesPos[i].Length) {
                    var prevLineArray = GetLineAsByteArray(prevPos);
                    var thisLineArray = GetLineAsByteArray(linesPos[i]);

                    if (prevLineArray.SequenceEqual(thisLineArray)) {
                        var line = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(prevLineArray);
                        duplicates.Add(line);
                    }
#if false
                    string prevLine = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(prevLineArray);
                    string thisLine = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(thisLineArray);

                    Console.WriteLine("PrevLine: {0}\r\nThisLine: {1}", prevLine, thisLine);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append(prevPos);
                    sb.Append(" is '");
                    sb.Append(prevLine);
                    sb.Append("'. ");
                    sb.AppendLine();
                    sb.Append(linesPos[i]);
                    sb.Append(" is '");
                    sb.Append(thisLine);
                    sb.AppendLine("'. ");
                    sb.Append("Equals => ");
                    sb.Append(prevLine.CompareTo(thisLine) == 0);
                    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
#endif

                }
                else {
                    prevPos = linesPos[i];
                }
            }
            return duplicates;
        }
    }
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        List<TextFileHasher> textFileHashers = new List<TextFileHasher>();
        string text1 = "abc\r\ncba\r\nabc";
        TextFileHasher tfh1 = new TextFileHasher("Text1", new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text1)));
        tfh1.CalculateFileHash();
        textFileHashers.Add(tfh1);

        string text2 = "def\r\ncba\r\nwet";
        TextFileHasher tfh2 = new TextFileHasher("Text2", new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text2)));
        tfh2.CalculateFileHash();
        textFileHashers.Add(tfh2);

        string text3 = "def\r\nbla\r\nwat";
        TextFileHasher tfh3 = new TextFileHasher("Text3", new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text3)));
        tfh3.CalculateFileHash();
        textFileHashers.Add(tfh3);

        List<string> totalDuplicates = new List<string>();

        Dictionary<ulong, Dictionary<TextFileHasher, List<LinePosition>>> totalHashes = new Dictionary<ulong, Dictionary<TextFileHasher, List<LinePosition>>>();
        textFileHashers.ForEach(tfh => {
            foreach(var dummyHash in tfh.Hashes) {
                Dictionary<TextFileHasher, List<LinePosition>> tfh2LinePositions = null;
                if (!totalHashes.TryGetValue(dummyHash, out tfh2LinePositions))
                    totalHashes[dummyHash] = new Dictionary<TextFileHasher, List<LinePosition>>() { { tfh, tfh.GetLinePositions(dummyHash) } };
                else {
                    List<LinePosition> linePositions = null;
                    if (!tfh2LinePositions.TryGetValue(tfh, out linePositions))
                        tfh2LinePositions[tfh] = tfh.GetLinePositions(dummyHash);
                    else
                        linePositions.AddRange(tfh.GetLinePositions(dummyHash));
                }
            }
        });

        HashSet<TextFileHasher> alreadyGotDuplicates = new HashSet<TextFileHasher>();

        foreach(var hash in totalHashes.Keys) {
            var tfh2LinePositions = totalHashes[hash];
            var tfh = tfh2LinePositions.Keys.FirstOrDefault();
            // Get duplicates in the TextFileHasher itself
            if (tfh != null && !alreadyGotDuplicates.Contains(tfh)) {
                totalDuplicates.AddRange(tfh.GetDuplicates());
                alreadyGotDuplicates.Add(tfh);
            }
            if (tfh2LinePositions.Count <= 1) {
                continue;
            }
            // Algo to get duplicates in more than 1 TextFileHashers
            var tfhs = tfh2LinePositions.Keys.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < tfhs.Length; i++) {
                var tfh1Positions = tfhs[i].GetLinePositions(hash);
                for (int j = i + 1; j < tfhs.Length; j++) {
                    var tfh2Positions = tfhs[j].GetLinePositions(hash);

                    for (int k = 0; k < tfh1Positions.Count; k++) {
                        var tfh1Pos = tfh1Positions[k];
                        var tfh1ByteArray = tfhs[i].GetLineAsByteArray(tfh1Pos);
                        for (int m = 0; m < tfh2Positions.Count; m++) {
                            var tfh2Pos = tfh2Positions[m];
                            if (tfh1Pos.Length != tfh2Pos.Length)
                                continue;
                            var tfh2ByteArray = tfhs[j].GetLineAsByteArray(tfh2Pos);

                            if (tfh1ByteArray.SequenceEqual(tfh2ByteArray)) {
                                var line = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(tfh1ByteArray);
                                totalDuplicates.Add(line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        if (totalDuplicates.Count > 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("Total number of duplicates: {0}", totalDuplicates.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("#######################");
            totalDuplicates.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}", x));
            Console.WriteLine("#######################");
        }
        // Free resources
        foreach (var tfh in textFileHashers)
            tfh.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I load `File.readlines` into it instead of a string of text in `main()`?

Comment: Instead of MemoryStream you can use FileStream. For eaxmple, TextFileHasher tfh1 = new TextFileHasher("Text1", new FileStream("PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));

Answer (score -1):

If you have tons of ram... You guys are overthinking it...

var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\file.csv").Distinct();